# Why does knowledge of $\langle 0| x^m p^n |0\rangle$ determine the ground state wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

As part of an exercise in Banks' QFT book (3.1) it is claimed that for a quantum mechanical system a knowledge of $\langle 0| x^m p^n|0 \rangle$ for all $n,m$ allows us to calculate the expression for the ground state wave function $\psi_{0}(x)$. I fail to see why this is so. Since the above matrix elements are simply numbers, my guess is that they are the coefficients in some expansion of $\psi_{0}(x)$, but I can't see the precise relation.

Comment: I haven't really attempted at some computations but I'd try to use exponentials here (think of their series expansion).

Comment: @SCFT Do you want a full answer or only a hint how to proceed?

Comment: @Sebastian Initially a hint would be good. But if I still can't figure it out, I'll ask for a full answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SCFT okay it is there (and with "cheating" it is a full answer, see the side note ;) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\left<#1\right>}\newcommand{\braopket}[3]{\left<#1\middle|#2\middle|#3\right>}$I will not provide a full solution, but a hint, that might help to proceed (I might later extend this to a full answer). The statement is related to the fact, that a probility density can be reconstructed from its moments (that is averages of the form $\avg{x^n}$). That is given $\avg{x^m}$ for all $m$ you can reconstruct $P(x)$. This can be seen as follows. Consider the characteristic function 
$$\chi(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, e^{-i\tau x} P(x) = \avg{e^{-i\tau x}}$$
By Taylor expansion of the $e$-function we get:
$$\chi(\tau) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\avg{(-i \tau x)^n}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{n!} \tau^n \avg{x^n}.$$
That means, that $\chi(\tau)$ can be computed from the moments, on the other hand $\chi(\tau)$ is the Fourier transform of $P(x)$, so
$$ P(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\tau t} \chi(\tau).$$

Side note: According to the Hohenberg-Kohn theorems the ground state wave function is fully determined by the ground state particle density (in a 1d system this holds for *all* bound states as those can be chosen real and so $\psi(x) = \sqrt{n(x)}$ will give a solution). So it is actually enough to know $\braopket{0}{x^n}{0}$ for all $n$, from which you can easily derive $n(x)$ (the probability density of finding a particle).

Comment: I think I got it. I apply your hint to $P(x) = |\psi(x)|^2$, and thus knowledge of the $\langle 0 | x^n | 0 \rangle $ allows me to get the Fourier transform of $P(x)$ and thus $P(x)$ by inversion. The modulus determines the wavefunction upto a phase.

Comment: Well, you still will have to fix the phase. I tried an ansatz $\psi(x) = \sqrt{P(x)} e^{i\phi(x)}$ and derived an equation for $\phi(x)$ from the moments with $p$ (just using the terms $\langle 0 \rvert p x^m \lvert 0 \rangle$), but that does not give a nice explicit solution, you can certainly generalize the above method somehow to get a nicer explicit formula. (But I have not seen yet how).

Comment: Okay yes, I glossed over that. If in addition we use knowledge of $\langle 0| p x^m |0\rangle $ like you say, we can determine both $|\psi|^2$ and $\psi^{*}(x) \psi'(x)$. Both of these are enough to determine the phase (upto a constant) as well. 

What is the nicer approach you are referring to?

Comment: I do not know it exists, but I guess one can construct something like the Wigner quasi-probability function from the moments (directly from the characteristic function) and then deduce the wave function from this (which is possible, but I am not sure how to do it).

Comment: By generalizing to two dimensions, one can determine $\psi^*(x) \hat{\psi}(p) e^{ipx}$ (which seems to be the Wigner quasi-probability function you mention). But then the problem remains of determining $\psi(x)$ from that.

Anyway, I think I have a fairly satisfactory understanding now. Thanks for your help!